# Latex: how to break a line inside $$

Tags: latex, newline, line-breaks, multiline, equation

I want to manually break a line inside `$$`:

```
$$something something <breakline> something else$$
```

I tried `\\`, `\newline`, and `\linebreak` but none work. Ideas?

Comment: Don't use `$$` for display math; you should instead use `\[` … `\]`.

Comment: thanks. this doesn't work however

Comment: And why do you want to break the line anyway? Let's see the actual text, not “something something etc.” because what you want will either be covered by an existing environment and you should use the right one, or just be bad typesetting practice.

Comment: @sgm: Why not use `$$`? Donald Knuth does.

Answer (score 30):

A couple of people have suggested `eqnarray` which will work, but a better approach is the align environment in the `amsmath` package.

```
\begin{align*}
something \\
something else
\end{align*}
```

If you want the two parts aligned in some way, use an `&` as described in the `amsmath` documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using the TeX-style `$$` commands, consider using the `align*` or `gather*` environments. Inside those, you can use the line break command `\\`.

(You will need to load the `amsmath` package to use those; but if you're doing any math at all, you should be loading that package regardless.)

Comment: Documentation at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A

Answer (score 5):

The way to get line breaks in display math, while using only standard LaTeX, is to use `\begin{array}...\end{array}` within the display math environment `$$...$$`. (Yes, I know that `$$` is deprecated but I still like it.)  There are many alternatives in different extensions, including AMSLaTeX's `align` and `align*` environments.  My personal favorite is Didier Rémy's [`mathpartir`](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/) package, which gives a display-math environment that is more like paragraph mode, plus a set of tools for typesetting logical inference rules and proof trees.

Answer (score 5):

11 years later...

An example of breaking text in multiple lines is having a cell with multiple lines in an array. Instead of using a new array row, you can break the text in lines within a cell. The advantage of doing this is interline space is not dependent on the whole row height (if some cell in the row has a large height, this won't influence the text interline space):

[image: Latex array cell with multiple lines]

To do this, just enclose the cell content within curly braces and use `\\` as a linebreak.

Content of the highlighted cell:

```
{ T_f (u) \text { is the transformed function and }
  \\
  K (t,u) \text { is the kernel used. }}
```

Whole code:

```
$\begin {array} {lll}
\text {Transform: } T_f (u) 
    & = \int \limits_{t_1}^{t^2} K (t,u) f(t) dt \;\; \textrm {where:}
        & {
            T_f (u) \text { is the transformed function and }
            \\
            K (t,u) \text { is the kernel used. }
          }
          \\
\text {Inverse transform: } f(u) 
    & = \int \limits_{u_1}^{u^2} K^{-1} (t,u) T_f(u) du
\end {array}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
    \documentclass[varwidth,margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{math}
                \alpha(e1)=c1,\ \alpha(e2)=c3\\
                \alpha(e3)=c5,\ \alpha(e4)=c2\\
                \alpha(e5)=c4,\ \alpha(e1)=c1\\
        \end{math}
    \end{document}
```

---

The `varwidth` parameter is the key.
With it you can properly utilize `\linebreak`, `\newline`, `\\`, etc.
I used `\begin{math}` / `\end{math}`, but you should be able to use the old `$` / `$$` notation too.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution in many cases (when a math mode is present inside a paragraph) can be to just split the single line $---segment1-----|--segment2-----$ in math mode (where a split is desired at the symbol "|") to  two consecutive segment each inside math mode as $---segment1-----$$--segment2-----$.

Answer (score -6):

You could use an eqnarray* instead.

Comment: sorry, don't understand how you're suggesting to use this. Can you add an example.

Comment: `gather` and `align` much better option